# Color shifts based on Frequency of Audio in react

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, web-audio-api

I am trying to create an audio visualizer of sorts. I just want to get a color based on the frequency of audio playing. I have tried to use the Web Audio API in the React Howler wrapper to analyze the frequency data of the playing audio and change the color based on the frequency. This involved creating an AudioContext and connecting it to the ReactHowler component, then creating an Analyser node to obtain the frequency data. The frequency data could then be used to manipulate the CSS color.

I have attempted to use audioContext to get the audio that is playing and get a frequency graph then average it to get an RGB value.

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import ReactHowler from "react-howler";
import {useRef, useState} from "react";
import {songs} from "../constants/songs";
import {IconPlayerPauseFilled, IconPlayerPlayFilled, IconPlayerSkipForwardFilled} from "@tabler/icons-react";


export function AudioPlayer() {
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [song, setSong] = useState(songs[0]);
    const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(true);
    const [firstPlay, setFirstPlay] = useState(false);
    const [frequencyColour, setFrequencyColour] = useState("blue");
    const audioRef = useRef(null)

    const analyzeFrequency = (audioContext, sourceNode) => {
        const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        sourceNode.connect(analyser);
        const dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

        const updateColor = () => {
            requestAnimationFrame(updateColor);
            analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
            const average = Math.floor(
                [...dataArray].reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / dataArray.length
            );
            const color = `rgb(${average}, ${255 - average}, ${0})`;
            setFrequencyColour(color);
        };
        console.log("analyzing frequency"+frequencyColour)
        updateColor();
    };


    const onLoadAudio = () => {
        const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        const sourceNode = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioRef.current);
        analyzeFrequency(audioContext, sourceNode);
    };

    const nextSong = () => {
        setPlaying(false);
        let index = songs.indexOf(song);
        if (index === songs.length - 1) {
            setSong(songs[0]);
        } else {
            setSong(songs[index + 1]);
        }
        setPlaying(true);
    }


    const play = () => {
        if (!firstPlay) {
            setFirstPlay(true);
        }
        setPlaying(true);
    }
    const pause = () => {
        setPlaying(false);
    }

    const newSong = () => {
        setPlaying(false);
        setPlaying(true);
        onLoadAudio();
    }



    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <ReactHowler
                    src={song.url}
                    playing={playing}
                    loop={false}
                    onEnd={nextSong}
                    onLoad={!initialLoad ? newSong : () => setInitialLoad(false)}
                    html5={true}
                    ref={song.url}
                    onLoadError={() => console.log("error")}
                />
                <div className={styles.audioplayer}>
                    <div style={{display: "flex", marginTop: "10px"}}>
                        {!playing ?
                            <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={play}><IconPlayerPlayFilled size={30} /></div> :
                            <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={pause}><IconPlayerPauseFilled size={30} /></div>
                        }
                        {firstPlay ?


                            <div style={{
                                display: "flex",
                                flexDirection: "column",
                                marginTop: "2px",
                                marginLeft: "10px",
                                padding: "0",

                            }}>
                                <div style={{fontSize: "12px", padding: "0"}}>{song.name}</div>
                                <div style={{fontSize: "12px", padding: "0"}}>{song.artist}</div>
                            </div>
                            :
                            <div style={{
                                display: "flex",
                                flexDirection: "column",
                                marginTop: "2px",
                                marginLeft: "10px",
                                padding: "0",

                            }}>
                                <div style={{fontSize: "12px", padding: "0"}}>Vibes</div>
                                <div style={{fontSize: "12px", padding: "0"}}>Curated By Me</div>
                            </div>
                        }

                    </div>

                    {firstPlay &&

                        <div className={styles.nextsong}
                        onClick={nextSong}
                        ><IconPlayerSkipForwardFilled size={30} />
                        </div>
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```